# Can't convert #pkc1 pgp private/public key to #pkc8

Tags: terminal, openssl, private-key, public-key, openpgp

**openSSL pkcs8 -in private-key.pem -topk8 -nocrypt -out private-pkc8.pk8**

I run this command and it prompts;
"Could not find private key of key from private-key.pem"

I can't seem to find a solution.

1. I looked it up and private/public key files are using **UTF-8**.
2. They start like this: **-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC(PRIVATE) KEY BLOCK----- -----END PGP PUBLIC(PRIVATE) KEY BLOCK-----**

I tried chaning these to various things but sadly none worked.

3. I tried this command;
   **sudo ssh-keygen -e -f private-key.pem -m PKCS8 > public-key.pem** //private-key being #pkc1

It prompts;
"Load key "private-key.pem": invalid format"

4. I also tried this command;
   **openssl rsa -RSAPublicKey_in -in public-key.pem -pubout**

It prompts;
unable to load Public Key
140704425797376:error:0908F066:PEM routines:get_header_and_data:bad end line:crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:852:

*Is there anything more I can try?*

Comment: Stackoverflow is for questions about programming and software development which this is not, but **your file is PGP format** which is NOT PKCS1 AND NOT PKCS8 AND NOT any format OpenSSL can read. OpenSSH (ssh-keygen) also can NOT read this format. Only tools designed for PGP can read it. Moreover a public key cannot _ever_ be converted to PKCS8, only a private key can. _IF_ an RSA private key is in PGP format, `gpg` can import it then `gpgsm` can [convert to 'SMIME' and output in PKCS8](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/238641#238681) ...

Comment: ... or as I stated there, personally I would just write a few lines of Java using BouncyCastle bcpg; note to write _unencrypted_ PKCS8 PEM you _can_ use PemWriter from Bouncy but don't really need to, plain Java with Base64.getMimeEncoder does most of it.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, i'm a newbie so pay no mind please. I would really appreciate if you could lead me to a forum for these type of questions.